# Terraform JSON config error "each.value cannot be used in this context"

Tags: json, foreach, terraform

My requirement is to create a dynamic resource connector in Kafka cluster. Below is my "**connector.tf**" file:

```
resource "confluent_connector" "source" {
  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.staging.id
  }
  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.id
  }

  config_sensitive = {
    "salesforce.password" : var.source_salesforce_password,
    "salesforce.password.token" : var.source_salesforce_password_token,
    "salesforce.consumer.key" : var.source_salesforce_consumer_key,
    "salesforce.consumer.secret" : var.source_salesforce_consumer_secret
  }

  config_nonsensitive = {
    "connector.class" : "SalesforceCdcSource",
    "kafka.auth.mode" : "KAFKA_API_KEY",
    "salesforce.cdc.name" : "AccountChangeEvent",
    "kafka.api.key" : confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.id,
    "kafka.api.secret" : confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.secret,
    "salesforce.instance" : var.source_salesforce_url,
    "salesforce.username" : var.source_salesforce_username,
    
    for_each = { for s in var.source_salesforce_connector_name : s.source_salesforce_connector_name => s },
    "name" : each.value["source_salesforce_connector_name"],
    "kafka.topic" : each.value["source_salesforce_topic_name"],
    "output.data.format" : each.value["source_salesforce_data_format"], 
    "tasks.max" : each.value["source_salesforce_max_task"]
  }

  depends_on = [
    confluent_kafka_topic.topic
  ]

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

Variable declaration as below: **variable.tf** file

```
variable "source_salesforce_connector_name" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [{
    "source_salesforce_connector_name" = "SalesforceCdcSourceConnector_0_TF"
  }]
}
```

And I am running this execution from **.tfvars** file:

```
source_salesforce_connector_name = [
    {
        source_salesforce_connector_name  = "SalesforceCdcSourceConnector_1_TF"
        source_salesforce_topic_name      = "json-topic-1"
        source_salesforce_data_format     = "JSON"
        source_salesforce_max_task        = "1"
    },
]
```

Getting below error with the execution, please suggest how to pass **for_each** condition into the JSON configuration as highlighted above.

I tried with above steps and execution, however getting below error:

```
terraform plan -var-file="DEV/DEV.tfvars"

Error: each.value cannot be used in this context

  on modules\confluent_kafka_cluster_dedicated\source_connector_salesforce_cdc.tf line 27, in resource "confluent_connector" "source":
    27:     "name" : each.value["source_salesforce_connector_name"],
    28:     "kafka.topic" : each.value["source_salesforce_topic_name"],
    29:     "output.data.format" : each.value["source_salesforce_data_format"],
    30:     "tasks.max" : each.value["source_salesforce_max_task"],*

 A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when    
 the configuration no longer contains the value in its "for_each" expression. Remove this        
 reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.
```

Comment: What do you aim to achieve with your `for_each`? Any example of the expected outcome?

Comment: @Marcin
Basically, want to create a multiple Connectors as per the user input in DEV.tfvars file. Defined a variable of type Map object and want to iterate this block for every new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple `confluent_connector` resources based on `var.source_salesforce_connector_name`, then your `for_each` should be outside of `config_nonsensitive`:

```
resource "confluent_connector" "source" {

  for_each = { for s in var.source_salesforce_connector_name : s.source_salesforce_connector_name => s },

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.staging.id
  }
  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.id
  }
  config_sensitive = {
    "salesforce.password" : var.source_salesforce_password,
    "salesforce.password.token" : var.source_salesforce_password_token,
    "salesforce.consumer.key" : var.source_salesforce_consumer_key,
    "salesforce.consumer.secret" : var.source_salesforce_consumer_secret
  }
  config_nonsensitive = {
    "connector.class" : "SalesforceCdcSource",
    "kafka.auth.mode" : "KAFKA_API_KEY",
    "salesforce.cdc.name" : "AccountChangeEvent",
    "kafka.api.key" : confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.id,
    "kafka.api.secret" : confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.secret,
    "salesforce.instance" : var.source_salesforce_url,
    "salesforce.username" : var.source_salesforce_username,
    "name" : each.value["source_salesforce_connector_name"],
    "kafka.topic" : each.value["source_salesforce_topic_name"],
    "output.data.format" : each.value["source_salesforce_data_format"], 
    "tasks.max" : each.value["source_salesforce_max_task"]
  }

  depends_on = [
    confluent_kafka_topic.topic
  ]

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```